# Cómo quitar un valor del pathname y entregar una url limpia

Tags: javascript

Necesito remover un valor / texto del pathname y entregar una url limpia precisamente sin pathname, qué puedo hacer para lograr esto?

```js
var url = window.location.href;
var search = url.indexOf("lang-es");

if (search != -1) {

// Necesito quitar el "lang-es" del pathname y entregar una url totalmente limpia

}
```

Comment: cómo serían un par de urls de ejemplo? cambia la ubicación ?

Comment: www.ejemplo.com/?lang=es //  www.ejemplo.com es decir quitar el lang=es

Comment: ahi va, es un parámetro ya te paso una function que remueve todos o alguno

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar usar ésta función [basada en una respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5818284/1423096) del usuario [@mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan)

Para quitar todos los parámetros la función se llama con false.

Para quitar sólo un parámetro usamos [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) pasándole los actuales, borrando el key indicado y luego concatenando el resultado con el llamado a la función para que devuelva sin parámetros.

Para agregar un parámetro es lo mismo, pero con dos opciones `URLSearchParams.set()` que reemplaza y `URLSearchParams.append()` que lo agrega ( parámetros multivalor se consiguen con `URLSearchParams.getAll()` )

Para obtener la url completa ( protocol, hostname, puerto, pathname ) con parámetros llamas a la función con true.

Si necesitas aparte lo que va después del `#` habría que agregar `window.location.hash`

```js
// location w/o hash https://stackoverflow.com/a/5818284/1423096

function getCurrentLocation(withParams) {
  var currentLocation = window.location.protocol + '//' +
    window.location.hostname +
    (window.location.port ? ":" + window.location.port : "") +
    window.location.pathname;
  if (withParams) {
    currentLocation += (window.location.search ? window.location.search : "");
  }
  return currentLocation;
}

// url sin parametros
console.log(getCurrentLocation(false))

// url sin un parámetro
let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
params.delete('lang');
currentLocation = getCurrentLocation(false) + 
  ( params.toString() ? '?' : '' ) +
  params.toString();
console.log(currentLocation);
```